# Transform an object into a context in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I have an Object like this:

```
var context = {
  "myBoolean" : true,
  "myNumber" : 5,
  "myObject" : {
    "attr1" : "value1"
  }
}
```

I have a String which is a condition:

```
var condition = "myBoolean == true && myNumber > 3 && myObject.attr1 == 'value1'"
```

I want to eval the String `condition` with `myBoolean`, `myNumber`, `myObject` taking their values inside context.

I was close to an answer with these lines :

```
eval("function doTest() { return " + condition + ";};"
    + "var answer = doTest.apply(context);");
```

But I need to add `this.` in front of my variable name. So it's not exactly what I want to do.

I know this doesn't sounds very nice/secure to do something like this, but I think an answer coule be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) does exactly this, appending an object to your scope:

```
var condition = "myBoolean == true && myNumber > 3 && myObject.attr1 == 'value1'"
var doTest = new Function("context", "with(context){ return "+condition+"; }");
var answer = doTest({
  "myBoolean" : true,
  "myNumber" : 5,
  "myObject" : {
    "attr1" : "value1"
  }
});
```

Notice that `with` and `eval` (or `Function`) are known for their bad performance, but it seems this is just what you need here.

Comment: Great discovery with the "with ! That's awesome, thanks Bergi !